# Turn over meaning

Tags: grammar

What does the phrase turn over imply in the sentence "She turned over from her contemplation of the photograph" ?

Comment: What is it you don’t understand about “turn”? Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Maybe she got uncomfortable when looking at it and awkwardly moved or shyly turned her head.

Comment: Where did you find it? It's not particularly idiomatic.

Comment: I found this sentence in Oxford dictionaries while searching for examples of contemplation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like "She"directed her attention to something else.